# Let $\alpha \in \overline{\Bbb Q}$ a root of $X^3+X+1\in\Bbb Q[X]$. Calculate the minimum polynomial of $\alpha^{-1}$ en $\alpha -1$.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $\alpha \in \overline{\Bbb Q}$ a root of $X^3+X+1\in\Bbb Q[X]$.
>   Calculate the minimum  polynomial of $\alpha^{-1}$ en $\alpha -1$.

I don't really understand how to get started here. I know that

$$\overline{\Bbb Q}=\{x\in \Bbb C : \text{ where $x$ is algegbraic over $\Bbb Q$} \}$$

A hint to get me started or a complete solution would be both very muchappreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a zero of a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$, what can you say about the zeros of the reciprocal polynomial $x^nf(1/x)$, and the translate $f(x+1)$?

Comment: A more taxing task would be to find the minimal polynomial of numbers like $\beta=\alpha^2+2\alpha+5$. Then you might need to resort to a more general method of writing $1,\beta,\beta^2,\beta^3(,\ldots)$ in terms of the monomial basis of $\Bbb{Q}[\alpha]$ consisting of powers of $\alpha$. Write their generic linear combination (with unknown coefficients), and solve the resulting linear system. In this case the above tricks take you the finish line right away.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: over any field $\;\Bbb F\;$ , suppose $\;0\neq w\;$ is a root of

$$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\implies a_0+a_1w+\ldots+a_nw^n=0\implies$$

$$\implies a_0w^{-n}+a_1w^{-n+1}+\ldots+a_n=0\;\ldots$$