# Use $\alpha, \beta, \gamma $ roots of a polynomial to construct another polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma $ be roots $\in \mathbb{C}$ of $x^3-3x+1$. Determinate a monic polynomial, degree $3$, witch roots are $1- \alpha^{-1},1-\beta^{-1},1-\gamma^{-1}$

The catch is that i can't use any formula to calculate the roots of $x^3-3x+1$ unless using the quadratic formula or the gauss theorem (though it might not be necessary)

Comment: Combine the tricks described [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/601514/11619). Close to being a dup? You also need the observation that the zeros of $f(-x)$ are the negtaives of the zeros of $f(x)$ :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $y=1-\frac 1 x$, you can write $x=\frac 1{1-y}$, then substituting in your equation $x^3-3x+1$ and simplifying, you get:

$$y^3-3y+1=0$$

Thus, if $x$ is a root of your polynomial, so is $1-\frac 1 x$.

Comment: very simple solution, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Consider $(x-1+\alpha^{-1})(x-1+\beta^{-1})(x-1+\gamma^{-1})$. Using Vieta's formulae, determine it's coefficients given the coefficients of $x^3-3x+1=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$.